# Django rest framework IntegrityError(1048, "Column 'Board_id' cannot be null")

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The error below occurs when attempting to create a comment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQRcz.png)

And my code is as follows. I want to know the solution.

Help me. I'm such a beginner.

**models.py**

```
class Board(models.Model):
    b_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    b_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    b_note = models.TextField(null=True, help_text="")
    b_writer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    b_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)
    b_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    usage_flag = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10, default='1')

class Comment(models.Model):
    Board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_writer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_note = models.TextField(null=True, help_text="")
    c_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['c_writer', 'c_note', 'c_date']


class CommentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['c_writer', 'c_note']
```

**views.py**

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    # lookup_field = 'no'
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentCreateSerializer

    # def form_vaild(self, form):
    #     comment = form.save(commit=False)
    #     comment.writer = self.request.user
    #     comment.board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=self.kwargs['board_pk'])
    #     return super().form_valid(form)

class CommentDeleteView(DestroyAPIView):
    # lookup_field = 'no'
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
path('boardapi/<int:board_pk>/comment/create/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='CommentCreateView'),
path('boardapi/<int:board_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/delete/', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='CommentDeleteView'),
```

Answer (score 0):

This article is helpful for you please read.
Class Based Views
While functions are easy to work with, it’s often beneficial to use class based views to reuse functionality, especially for large APIs with a number of endpoints.
https://realpython.com/django-rest-framework-class-based-views/

Comment: I am not good at English. So I don't know even if I look at the site you told me.